# What's the best way to extract data from Sharepoint to SQL server database?

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, database

The source data are from MS Project on SharePoint. The business would like to see the updates of MS project near real time. We have the reports pulling the MS project data off SQL server database. Right now, we are using SSIS package to get the MS project data from SharePoint to the database, but it's slow or get disconnected.

Comment: Are you using Project Server?

Comment: No. The Office 365 Project is synched with SharePoint, which is on the cloud.

Comment: Could you explain more what data is stored in SharePoint? Is it tasks list information?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the powershell with SharePoint CSOM and write the custom code to extract the data in to your external database as needed.

Pls refer the below link to get an overview on CSOM with powershell.

[Reference Link](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html)